# IndentationError: unexpected indent when returning a variable after form submission

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm new to Flask and started exploring with simple functionalities. The idea is to have a form with just one field and read this form data and pass it to another function to do something else. So for now, I was able to set up Flask correctly and running.

When a user submits the form, I'm able to see the value if I return some text like "form submitted". But I'm getting an error when I do this.

What I did: When a user submits, instead of returning a hard coded text, I should return the HTML source code of a website. For this purpose, I'm using urllib2 and as a sample passing google.com URL. But I get some IndentationError.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app
from forms import LoginForm
import urllib2
# index view function suppressed for brevity
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Login requested for OpenID="' + form.openid.data + '", remember_me=' + str(form.remember_me.data))
        #return "form submitted" #This is working properly
        response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com") # Here is the problem, I'm consistent in using spaces if I comment this and below line and uncomment above hard coded one, it works perfectly 
        return response


    return render_template('login.html', 
        title = 'Sign In',
        form = form)
```

Traceback for your reference.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "C:\Python27\projects\pnr-project\app\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "C:\Python27\projects\pnr-project\app\views.py", line 12
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What am I missing here? please let me know.

Comment: Seems like you might have a mix of tabs and spaces for your indentation.

Comment: @NickBastin Thanks for the response, I just added some comments in my code. I only have the problem with that line as I mentioned.

Comment: Use your code editor functionality: show white-spaces, convert tabs to spaces, also PEP8 plug-in. These should help you.

Comment: @viktor.likin I'm not sure if this is problem with spaces. urllib2 works in webserver? I mean in flask locally.

Comment: I've received such problems:) I guess you have problem with indents after **if**. Because an error is invoked when the form is submitted. The error trace says you have the problem before the word - **response**.

Comment: @viktor.likin I tweaked few lines in there, response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
  html = response.read()
  return html  and it worked

Comment: @viktor.likin I have used python interactive editor and debugger line by line..

Answer (score -2):

Worked, finally. I tried debugging line by line and below modification worked!

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
        html = response.read()
        return html
```

Comment: That is an `IndentationError` par excellence.